# Odometer Speedometer jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any plugin who give's the chart type = ODOMETER ?

incrideble how is so hard to find this, even highchart's that i'm using ( very good chart library ) dont have a odometer, dont know why.

i found some "speedometer", [Demo](http://jacob-king.com/demo/speedometer) but wont help-me.

anyone know any plugin or something like who work with odometer's ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge.html)

Super easy to use and well documented.

---

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['Memory', 80],
          ['CPU', 55],
          ['Network', 68]
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 400, height: 120,
          redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
          yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
          minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);

        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(0, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 13000);
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(1, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 5000);
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(2, 1, 60 + Math.round(20 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 26000);
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 400px; height: 120px;"></div>
```

Comment: is the google chart that i cant download the source ? i'm checking him out right now.

Comment: See [Loading the Libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs.html)

Answer (score 1):

Let this question up-to-date. New features from [**highcharts**](http://www.highcharts.com/), i was looking for this, and now they have available:

[**Highcharts gauge-speedometer**](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-speedometer)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript speedometer plugin is available.

https://github.com/rmanivannan/speedometer-jquery-plugin

may be this could help